# What is the difference between launching a Mac OS X app via the Finder/open and executing the app binary directly?

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, launch-services

I'm experiencing an issue with a Qt app on Mac OS X 10.10.5, whereby a `QFileDialog` will not close properly when canceled. While this may be a bug in Qt, I only see this bug when running the app as a normal user would, e.g. opening it in the Finder (or via command line `open`). If I launch the app via Xcode or by calling the binary directly, there is no issue.

1. Launch the app via calling the binary directly on the command line or within Xcode, e.g. `./MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`
2. Launch the app via the Finder or `open`, e.g. `open ./MyApp.app`

What are the differences between these two methods - and how does it impact a running application?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly happens when the dialog doesn't close properly?

Comment: Please post a self-contained test case, and mention what exact Qt version you are using. If I can reproduce it, I'll ask you to file a bug report with that very test case.

Comment: I've posted some test code on [github](https://github.com/surething/filedialog) … and have reproduced it using a self-built Qt 5.3 and a Homebrew-installed Qt 5.5

Comment: Also, an interesting issue is that this only affects the app if `QFileDialog::open` or `QFileDialog::show` is used … and not if the convenience static methods `QFileDialog::get*` are used.

Comment: While the source of the problem wasn't discovered, a workaround was achieved using QML file dialogs instead of `QFileDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

The major difference is the working folder. You don't have any control over what it is, but it will be different between the two invocations.

What directory are you showing the `QFileDialog` in? You should probably start in a well-defined place, like the user's home.

Comment: The dialog is set to open in certain well-defined locations on disk, among them the user's home.

Comment: Every time the file dialog is invoked (not in the example code), the directory in which to open is set. While it'd be great to see this uncover a bug in Qt, I'm interested in why the two different ways of launching the app results in different behaviour.